# Minimizing function in two variables

Tags: calculus, optimization

Consider $F(x,y)$ is to be minimized. I proceed to solve this as follows:

Given any $y$, solve for $x^*(y)$ that minimizes $F(x,y)$;  And $x^*(y)$ is verified to be unique minimum for given $y$.

Now, plugging $x^*(y)$ back into $F(x,y)$, we get $F(x*^(y),y)=:G(y)$. Suppose we can verify $y^*$ is the unique solution to minimize $G(y)$. Then can we say that $(x^*(y^*), y^*)$ is the unique solution to minimize $F(x,y)$?

Is this approach okay?

Answer (score 0):

If your function allows for such an approach, then yes it works - by construction, $F(x^*(y^*), y^*)$ is smaller than $F(x^*(y), y)$ for any $y \neq y^*$, and similarly $F(x^*(y), y)$ is smaller than $F(x, y)$ for any $x \neq x^*(y)$, therefore it is the minimum value.